# Applications of graph colouring to pattern matching?

Tags: pattern-matching, graph-coloring

The Wikipedia article on graph colouring (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring) states

> The problem of coloring a graph has found a number of applications, including pattern matching.

However, it gives no references to this claim.  I've tried Googling, but what few relevant hits I get are just as opaque.

How does graph colouring apply to pattern matching?

Edit: I realize this is not specifically a problem about actual written programming, and so might not be the best fit for SO.  However, pattern matching is more relevant to programmers (for example, it's used a lot in Haskell) than it is to mathematicians, so I figured I'd have better luck here than in a math Q&A.  If there's a better place to put this question, I'll happily take it down and post it there.

Comment: Try scholar.google.com with the terms "graph coloring" and "pattern matching".  If somebody has written about it, this will likely turn up an answer.  Interested in what you find.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Following up on it, I did find a few articles via Google Scholar.  It'll take me a while to finish reading the relevant sections, but I'll report back with my findings.

Comment: I still haven't found a definitive answer.  The best thing I dug up was this paper (found by accident when looking up something else):  http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/colpr.pdf
My sense is that the meaning of "colouring" in the context of pattern matching is not the same as in the graph colouring article, but more in the sense of graph labelling http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_labeling